# How to send image and description to the server using retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am sending the image and it's description to the server using retrofit but i am unable to resolve getFile method in FileUtils.getFile method.

Here is my code:

gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.boxme:squarecamera:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
  compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.4')
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
}
```

Activity :

```
@NonNull
    private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {
        // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
        // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
        File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);// here i am not able to resolve getFile method 

        // create RequestBody instance from file
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse(context.getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                        file
                );
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);


    }
```

Comment: Where does that class come from? Have you been to the API documentation for that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have imported the wrong class

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

```
getFile(File directory, String... names)
```

I don't think `this` is a File object

Versus

com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils

```
getFile(Context context, String uri)
```

Comment: hello @cricket_007 , can you please tell me which library i have to add in gradle

Comment: Read the comment already in your code... The github link? That's the class you have to import. You imported commons io instead

Comment: In other words, wherever you  copied that code from, go back and read over it again

Comment: thnku for the help

Comment: AFAIK, you add nothing to gradle, you download this file directly into your project https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java